# how to Save bitmap image into my gallery folder in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, bitmapimage, android-bitmap

This is my code for saving the image. I have mentioned the folder name also in which I want to save the image so it will be in gallery but its not working my Image is getting saved in default "Pictures" folder. When I debug, it shows

*java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/MyFolderName/aaa-13:15:44/1-4-2016.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)*

exception. It goes to catch folder just after executing first line of try block.

Help please, what I am missing????

thank you in advance...

```
    public void saveImage(Bitmap bitmap){
    String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File myDir = new File(root + "/MyFolderName"); //my folder name where I want to save.
    String receiverN = receiverName.getText().toString();

    myDir.mkdirs();
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    String month, day, year, hour, minute, second;
    month = ""+ (c.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1);
    day = "" + c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    year = "" + c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    hour = ""+c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    minute = "" + c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    int seconds = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
    if (seconds<10) second = "0"+ seconds;
    else second = ""+seconds;

    String fname = receiverN + "-" + hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second + "/"  + month + "-" + day + "-" + year +".jpg";
    File file = new File (myDir, fname);
    if (file.exists ()) file.delete ();
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file); //from here it goes to catch block
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        String[] paths = {file.toString()};
        String[] mimeTypes = {"/image/jpeg"};
        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, paths, mimeTypes, null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things to try.

Use `File.separator` for your `/` character.

Instead of converting the external storage directory to string, use it in the `File` constructor.

```
File myDir = new File( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),File.separator+"MyFolderName");
```

Your actual file's name has a `/` in it. I would remove that character plus any other characters that may cause problems from file names using something like the following.

```
public static String encodeString(String string) {

        if (string != null) {
            string = string.replace("/","-");
            string = string.replace(" ","_");
            string = string.replace(":", "-");
            string = string.replace("&", "-");
        }
        return string;
    }
```

Comment: thank you very much.....its that "/" in the file name. I replaced it with "-" and it worked. However, as per your list I have ":" in my file name....no problem appeared because of that till now but "/" created issue. Any suggestions...?

Comment: `:` may not have created an issue. I guess it's down to your preference as to file name structure etc. If it doesn't cause a problem then maybe it's ok to use